# What is the best way to request input from user

Tags: html

I want to request info from user. See example below:

```
Your Name: |_________|
      Age: |_________|
  Address: |_________|
```

What is the best way to code the above in HTML?

1. It is best to implement it in **div**. Have left and right **div** for `label` and `input`
2. It is best to implement it in **table**

Comment: imo, a table would be the easiest way to implement a simple form like you want. its pretty trivial to do.

Answer (score 5):

1. No
2. No

You only need the labels and inputs.

```
label {
  width: 16em; /* Adjust for taste */
  padding-right: 1em;
  text-align: right;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
```

Comment: and if you want a "block" for the form to be in style the "form" tag.

Comment: Every couple would also be inserted in a <li>: the form contains a LIST of ITEMs. First child of the form would then be a UL

Answer (score 0):

Form styling via CSS is clean and practical, and has the added benefit of using HTML markup in the way it was intended.

Your form HTML can be written like this:

```
<form>
    <label>Your Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="your_name" /><br />
    <label>Age:</label>
    <input type="text" name="age" /><br />
    <label>Address:</label>
    <input type="text" name="address" /><br />
</form>
```

Your CSS will look like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    form label {
      float: left;
      width: 100px;
      text-align: right;
      }

    form input {
      float: left;
      width: 335px;
      text-align: left;
      }
    form br {
      clear: both;
    }
</style>
```

Tables are designed for tabular data. If you would expect to see your data in a spreadsheet, you can use it in an HTML table. Otherwise, CSS should be used to style your layout.

Answer (score -1):

Any more I do forms in a `table` since I hate fighting with the differences in browsers with how they position controls with css.

Comment: Tables may be easier from a beginners perspective but in the long run using more logical markup will save a lot of time and confusion. It's also allot easier to change the layout of the site in the future as you will only need to tweak some css styles. Not saying that you should never use tables, but really their not designed for layouts

Comment: I don't disagree. However, I find with any **sufficiently complex** layout I waste more time fighting with css hacks to get the layout to look right in all browsers (damn you IE!) than if I just use a table and position the table with css.

Comment: I agree with Dave. The approach doesn't really matter much if it's a small form, but anything complex becomes overly burdensome to handle with CSS alone and is much more easily handled with a table which provides a natural grid structure.